# Class constructor FormControl cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-reactive-forms

I have a simple [Angular 13 repo](https://github.com/GeorgeKnap/angular-jest-ng-stack-forms) where `@ng-stack/forms` is used like

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@ng-stack/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
})
export class AppComponent {
  control = new FormControl<string>('');
}
```

When I run Jest test I got an error:

```
> example-app-v13@13.0.0 test
> jest --no-cache

 FAIL  src/app/app.component.spec.ts
  AppComponent
    × should create the app (54 ms)                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                
  ● AppComponent › should create the app                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                
    TypeError: Class constructor FormControl cannot be invoked without 'new'

       7 | })
       8 | export class AppComponent {
    >  9 |   control = new FormControl<string>('');
         |             ^
      10 | }
      11 |

      at new FormControl (node_modules/projects/forms/src/lib/form-control.ts:42:5)
      at new AppComponent (src/app/app.component.ts:9:13)
      at NodeInjectorFactory.AppComponent_Factory [as factory] (ng:\AppComponent\ɵfac.js:5:10)
      at src/app/app.component.spec.ts:16:29

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total                                                                                                                                  
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total                                                                                                                                  
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.825 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Can anyone explain where is this error coming from and how to fix it?

Comment: The released version of this library doesnt support Angular 13 yet. It uses umd format of bundle under the hood. I'd ping the creator of this library because he already has some changes for Angular 13.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the issue. After upgrading to beta version test passes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by upgrade of `@ng-stack/forms` to version 3.0.0beta

Answer (score 0):

[Github link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18067)

Found something on angular-cli issues about your error, please take a look.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).